# Does anyone know of a good example of adding collectable items to unity tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am struggling to add tiles that are collectables to the unity 2d tilemap. If I do it with a trigger then I can't find which tile I collided with. If I do it via a normal collision then it works but the player is effected by hitting the tile...(ie bounces off just before the tile is removed)

Comment: However you're doing it with collisions should work just fine with triggers. All the same information is passed for both events.

Comment: No it is not. In triggers it gets a Collider2d passed in and for colliders it gets a collision2d passed in. collision2d has hitpoints while collider2d does not.

Comment: What do you need the hit location for?

Comment: So I can work out which tile was hit.

Comment: `OnTrigger(Collider2d other) { other.gameObject }`

Comment: That gives me the entire tilemap not the specific tile.

Comment: @coolblue2000 did you figure it out?